# sudo apt-get update failes due to Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: apt, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` I get four Hash Sum mismatch errors:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch    
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch    
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/main/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch    
W: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

I tried fixing this with

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
sudo apt-get update
```

but that didn't work and neither did

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
```

Is there any other way I can try to fix this?

Comment: I used the commands `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` then `sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order::=gz` before it worked for me (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1785778)

Answer (score 29):

Run these commands in terminal [1](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/09/27/fixing-apt-hash-sum-mismatch-consistent-apt-repositories/):

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

That worked for me. :-)

[Reference](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2016/09/27/fixing-apt-hash-sum-mismatch-consistent-apt-repositories/)

Comment: That worked! In order to avoid deleting the lists folder, you should better execute `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Answer (score 2):

Usually switching to another mirror does the trick. It's easy in the GUI, but I suspect you want a CLI solution.

`sudo sed -i 's|http://us.|http://|g' /etc/apt/sources.list` edits your sources.list in-place to use the main server from the US mirror. You can substitute other mirrors, `sudo sed -i 's|http://us.|http://fr.|g' /etc/apt/sources.list` would choose the french server, starting from the US server.

If you switch to the main server like in the first line, be warned that simple swapping your search and replace terms to get the US mirror back would break your security and extras repos, if you use them. You would need to run a second `sudo sed -i 's|http://us.security|http://security|g' /etc/apt/sources.list` line to account for that, repeated for extras instead of security.

Comment: The second command is iffy, `sources.list` may have the Canonical extras repository and `security.ubuntu.com` in it, neither of which have country-specific mirrors.

Answer (score 0):

Manually download the packages that are getting the *Hash Sum Mismatch* error and copy them to

```
/var/cache/apt/archive
```

Then again run

```
apt-get install <package-name>
```

It should now run correctly.

Comment: This looks like a useful suggestion; however I believe something is required to make `apt` know about a  `.deb` file manually downloaded into `/var/cache/apt/archives` - such as making an entry into `pkgcache.bin` -  but I haven't found a way to do this.  As things stand I'm getting `E: Unable to locate package $pkg`