# Problem with update ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: updates

Today I am trying to update my os. Now i am using ubuntu 15.10 and when i was trying to update, it shows this error:

```
Failed to fetch 
http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb 
Hash Sum mismatch 
Failed to fetch 
http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1_all.deb 
Hash Sum mismatch


rr Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  Temporary failure resolving 'bd.archive.ubuntu.com'                          
Get:1 Upgrade tool [1,266 kB]                                                  
Fetched 1,266 kB in 6s (55.7 kB/s)                                             
WARNING:root:file 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

Can anyone help about this ??

Answer (score 0):

Just type in the following commands to fix the errors

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run the actual system update

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-3.0-0_2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/firefox/firefox_50.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: Now i get this eror i was try sevaral time but no result :(

Comment: this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760574/sudo-apt-get-update-failes-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch

Comment: Could you post the output of the sources.list in your question, its located at /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Now get this eror :(   Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/webkitgtk/libwebkitgtk-3.0-0_2.4.11-0ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb Hash Sum mismatch

Comment: and also this  :( Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_1.004+repack2-1~ubuntu1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch