# Unable to install Wine on Xubuntu

Tags: wine

I am trying to install wine on xubuntu 16.10 x64. I am following the guide from here: https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu. I enabled 32 bit architecture and added the repository but when i run 'sudo apt-get update' i get this:

```
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety InRelease
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates InRelease [102 kB]       
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports InRelease [102 kB]                
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.9 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [15.7 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [18.7 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [18.4 kB]
Get:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main i386 Packages [228 kB]                                
Get:10 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 Packages [232 kB]
Get:11 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety InRelease [4,672 B]
Get:12 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [146 kB]
Get:13 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [82.2 kB]  
Get:14 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages [3,228 B]
Err:14 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Checksum-FileSize:3228 [weak]
   - SHA256:4d6ff0956b21c1f7b4d02d3bf3067cc5753e99467ef05260e7b53bde9fbe25ad
   - SHA1:22d80ec32c8945f8c77b89715da530770c79b6b0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:936a2931f0d4981fa8bfb9f92439ded0 [weak]
  Hashes of received file:
   - SHA256:0164eda0d063d33baf2892527b84c7a8bf15a0da001702d64e45673bdc84b820
   - SHA1:8d67ce71ad303248be3450fb92b93db70c83cbad [weak]
   - MD5Sum:9514718ff1baedbfbffe7681584aa6ba [weak]
   - Checksum-FileSize:1896 [weak]
  Last modification reported: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 19:54:53 +0000
  Release file created at: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 22:00:26 +0000
Get:15 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe i386 Packages [143 kB]
Get:16 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 Packages [3,252 B]
Get:17 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe amd64 Packages [145 kB]
Get:18 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [111 kB]
Get:19 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [144 kB]
Get:20 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Fetched 1,615 kB in 3s (469 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages.xz  Hash Sum mismatch
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Checksum-FileSize:3228 [weak]
    - SHA256:4d6ff0956b21c1f7b4d02d3bf3067cc5753e99467ef05260e7b53bde9fbe25ad
    - SHA1:22d80ec32c8945f8c77b89715da530770c79b6b0 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:936a2931f0d4981fa8bfb9f92439ded0 [weak]
   Hashes of received file:
    - SHA256:0164eda0d063d33baf2892527b84c7a8bf15a0da001702d64e45673bdc84b820
    - SHA1:8d67ce71ad303248be3450fb92b93db70c83cbad [weak]
    - MD5Sum:9514718ff1baedbfbffe7681584aa6ba [weak]
    - Checksum-FileSize:1896 [weak]
   Last modification reported: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 19:54:53 +0000
   Release file created at: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 22:00:26 +0000
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
osboxes@osboxes:~$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package winehq-staging
```

Comment: Have you followed exactly as described in the "Add the repository" section? No error messages? Try downloading and adding the release.key again (steps 1 and 2 + apt-get update). If no errors and the problem persists then there's an authentication problem with that repository and nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo apt-get update failes due to Hash Sum mismatch](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760574/sudo-apt-get-update-failes-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch)