# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Failed to fetch / Hash Sum mismatch

Tags: apt, updates, hash

Here's what I keep getting when I sudo apt update

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]     
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3-staging/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial InRelease      
Hit:7 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
Get:9 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/gnome-software/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:15 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:18 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server xenial InRelease
Get:19 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [540 kB]
Err:19 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
Get:21 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en [218 kB]
Get:22 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [298 kB]
Get:23 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [193 kB]
Get:24 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,776 B]
Get:25 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages [7,792 B]
Get:26 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,548 B]
Get:27 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [157 B]
Get:28 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [468 kB]
Get:29 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [453 kB]
Fetched 847 kB in 6s (121 kB/s)                                                
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/7ce67f72031f7cd7c4f24fffe8c90101935c8ae4e58502b1b60dfbb900f58841  Hash Sum mismatch
E: Failed to fetch http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/b4989c055e8da5afab24c96f86caf7157df19e46797e1217ad03a87d1b4a705a  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have tried many solutions of similar related issue, but nothing worked for me :( Please help!

Edit: Solutions I found in Google that didn't work for me:

- ["hash sum mismatch" error when doing update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846767/hash-sum-mismatch-error-when-doing-update)
- [sudo apt-get update failes due to Hash Sum mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760574/sudo-apt-get-update-failes-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch)
- [Trouble downloading packages list due to a "Hash sum mismatch" error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error)

Comment: What solutions have you tried so we don't re-offer stale solutions, Please look at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605/trouble-downloading-packages-list-due-to-a-hash-sum-mismatch-error

Comment: Edited. This was one of them too. didn't work :(

Comment: Please run `apt -v` and tell me what version shows up

Comment: Have you tried changing repositories? More than likely the repo isn't the issue, but it would rule that out.

Comment: @George apt 1.2.20 (amd64)

Comment: @b_laoshi Could you give me more details, please?

Comment: You can change your repo as shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/682576/606758).

Comment: See the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/891529/software-updater-issue-16-04/891532#891532)

Comment: @SirajusSalekin Thank you so much. You saved my day :D It worked. :)

Answer (score 5):

Run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
```

Comment: the error persists